# Restricting the awk output of df sum to 2 decimal points

Tags: awk, floating-point

I have a script to calculate the cumulative capacity in all the servers.

```
for i in `cat servers`
do
ssh user@$i "df -t xfs --total | grep total";
done > capout.txt
awk -vDT="Capacity" '
        {sum2 += $2
         sum3 += $3
         sum4 += $4
         sum5 += $5
        }
END     {GIGA=2^30
          print DT,"\t" sum2/GIGA,"\t" sum3/GIGA,"\t" sum4/GIGA ,"\t"  sum3/sum2*100
        }' capout.txt >> capacity.csv
```

Script works fine and i am getting the output as below.

```
Capacity   1047.43         439.4   608.032         41.9502
```

However i do not want to have the 3 trailing decimal points, I just need to restrict to one or two decimal points here.

Comment: THe answer to your question would be to use `printf("%d\n", sum3/GIGA....)` formatting. The script as written has bugs and should be recosidered: Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/094  and  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Comment: Try adding a `-v OFMT=%.2f`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I don't think i have got you completely. But i have tried below and seems it is not giving me any output.... printf(DT,"%d\t" sum2/GIGA,"%d\t" sum3/GIGA,"%d\t" sum4/GIGA ,"%d\t"  sum3/sum2*100)

Comment: @xrkr `printf` doesn't work that way. You first define  the formatting than place the variables i.e `printf("%s %d\t%d\t", DT,sum2/GIGA,sum3/GIGA)}'`  and so on. But I think you should also follow Stephanes' advise. Set the Output format to `%.2f`. This means you'll only get 2 digits after the dot `.`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Stéphane Chazelas Thanks it worked.